# how to convert a list into a list of tuples?

Tags: python

Here's what I have in the text file:

```
1712 Albert
1703 Benny
1799 Henry
1735 Jessica
1722 Lucas
1701 Luke
1757 William
1777 Jenny
1783 Lucia
1764 Venus
1718 Felicitas
```

Here's what I have done to read the file but I have no idea how to put them into a list of tuples

```
def readRecords(filepath):
    file = open('Students1.txt', 'r')
    filecontent = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return filecontent
```

Here's what the output is supposed to be:

[image: Output file]

Answer (score 1):

```
def readRecords(filepath):
    result = []
    with open('Students1.txt', 'r') as f:  # close the file outside of `with`
        for line in f:  # Iterate over lines
            num, name = line.split()  # split line into two part
            num = int(num)  # convert number part to `int`
            result.append((num, name))
    return result
```

NOTE: Don't use `readlines()` unless you need whole lines at once. You just need a line at a time; iterating a file is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file, and then split these lines, I realized that the result you need is like `(int, string)` ,so you can use `map` to do this and then return tuple:

```
with open('out.csv') as f:
    print([tuple(map(lambda x: int (x) if x.isdigit() else x,i.split())) for i in f])
```

Output:

```
[(1712, 'Albert'), (1703, 'Benny'), (1799, 'Henry'), (1735, 'Jessica'), (1722, 'Lucas'), (1701, 'Luke'), (1757, 'William'), (1777, 'Jenny'), (1783, 'Lucia'), (1764, 'Venus'), (1718, 'Felicitas')]
```

Comment: Required output is an (int, string) pair, not a (string, string)

Answer (score 1):

```
def readRecords(filepath):
   rst = []
   with open(filepath) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        rst = [(int(x.split(' ')[0]), x.split(' ')[1]) for x in data]
   return rst
```

Comment: please note the required output format is (int, string), not (string, string)

Comment: @JonKiparsky Thanks for that, I've refined my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over the lines in the file you just read. Here's what you could do:

```
def readRecords(filepath):
    file = open(filepath, 'r')  # You should use the filepath variable you've given
    filecontent = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    my_tuples = []
    for line in filecontent:  # For each line in the file...
        line = line.strip()  # Remove the newline character which you likely don't want
        my_tuples.append(int((line.split(' ')[0]), line.split(' ')[1]))  # Create a tuple of the two words separated by a space

    return my_tuples

print(readRecords('Students1.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the lines as you're reading them from the file, the following will work:

```
def process_lines(lines):
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.strip().split(" ")
        result.append(tuple(int(parts[0]), parts[1]))
    return result
```

A list comprehension is possible here, but it requires a lot of straining. Use listcomps when they simplify your code, avoid them when they make it more complicated. (or when they require you to calculate the same value twice)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice short two line method:

```
lines = [x.rstrip() for x in open('students.txt')]
output = [tuple(pair.split(' ')) for pair in lines]

print(output)
# [('1712', 'Albert'), ('1703', 'Benny'), ('1799', 'Henry')...
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Location = ["1712","1703","1799",...]
Name = ["Albert","Benny","Henry",...]
```

using a zip function:

```
z = zip(Location, Name)
print z
```

Output:

```
[("1712","Albert"),("1703","Benny"),...]
```

Comment: Required output is an (int, string) pair, not a (string, string)

Comment: Also, input comes from a file, not a pair of lists